# I want to display all employees grouped by department

Tags: sql

How do I write an SQL query that does this for the data I have

Employee

```
EMP_ID, DEPT_ID, NAME
1        1       A
2        1       B
3        1       C
4        2       D
5        2       E
```

Department

```
DEPT_ID, NAME
1        SALES
2        INVENTORY
```

Output of SQL

```
SALES
1  A
2  B
3  C
INVENTORY
4  D
5  E
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3):

This is not how SQL works.  SQL works (for simplicity) on tables, where the tables have well defined columns and zero or more rows.

Your result set has some rows with one column and some with two.

The SQL result set would typically look like:

```
1  A    SALES
2  B    SALES
3  C    SALES
4  D    INVENTORY
5  E    INVENTORY
```

You would generate this with a simple `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select e.id, e.name, d.name as dept_name
from employee e join
     department d
     on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
order by d.name, e.id;
```

Although you *could* create the result set you specify in SQL (basically by doing string manipulations), that sort of manipulation is usually done outside the database in the application layer.